# Are periodic geodesics always dense?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, dynamical-systems, geodesic

Let $M$ be a smooth closed Riemannian manifold, and let $p 
\in M$. Given $v \in T_pM$, let $\gamma_{p,v}$ be the geodesic emanating from $p$ with initial velocity $v$.

Define $A=\{ v \in T_pM |  \, \gamma_{p,v} \, \text{ is periodic } \}$. Is $A$ always dense in $T_pM$?

I am especially interested in dimension $2$. The example I have in mind is the flat torus $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{S}^1 \times \mathbb{S}^1$ where the velocities with rational values are dense.

Comment: Some quick googling turns up [this](https://www.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~salvai/cerraddp.pdf), which suggests the problem has been studied before and the answer is no without extra assumptions: *M is said to have the DPG property (density of periodic geodesics) if the vectors tangent to periodic geodesics in M are dense in TM, the tangent bundle of M. A compact manifold is known to have this property if, for example, its geodesic flow is Anosov (see [1]), in particular if it is hyperbolic.* ... *not every compact quotient of a Lie group endowed with a left invariant metric has the DPG property.*

Comment: Yes, thanks, I also found this. I guess I need to search more deeply to find a concrete counter-example.

Comment: No, even in the surface case, at least when genus is $\ge 2$, see “ Counterexamples in non-positive curvature” by  Coudene and Shapira.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you, I will take a look.